# How to split a list of names contained in option tags javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a list of names:

```
Berry, Barry
Altimar, Bonnie
Flopsy, Tonny
Marildoo, Barby
Dalibutton, Fling
```

These have been populated as through option tags.  Via ajax, I have users adding a name to the list. I would like to have it sorted...

How the heck do I split the string?

I did it as

```
var split = myList.split(",");
alert (split);
```

Which of course left me with

```
Berry, BarryAltimar, BonnieFlopsy, TonnyMarildoo, BarbyDalibutton, Fling
```

Boo.

I can't think of how to split it... I'm sure it's easy, but, as a novice, I'm stumped. I tried using "\n" and "\n\r", but of course those don't work, as the user is not pressing enter.

Any help = greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `myList`? String, textfield, something else?

Comment: It is a list that has been populated via an xml sheet. It is in a dropdown list that is being added to via 'the ajax'. var newOption = { buyer_email: buyer_name } myList = $('#myList'); $.each(newOption, function (val, text) { myList.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var split is an array and you need to access it as split[0]....split[n] instead of split.

Try this code

```
for(i=0;i<split.length;i++)
 alert(split[i]);
```

By the way mylist itself an array i guess. You should be doing mylist[0].split(',')[0] to get the first row first column value

Answer (score 1):

alert() likely calls function .toString() which returns comma separated values when applied to Array.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, how about:

```
var split = myList.replace(/\,/g, "").split(" ");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ChxhW/)**.